# Purchasing a license for enterprise GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, licensing, activation

After recent software update I have found the following message from program `glat-client` in system logs of some systems:

> This copy of GNU/Linux is not activated. See
>   https://gitlab.com/glat-official/howtotell for details.

What does it mean? Should I 'activate' my GNU/Linux copies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should remove this `glat-client` from your affected systems, and treat this as a potential security compromise.

Looking at the source code repositories for this so-called [glat-official](https://gitlab.com/glat-official), we can see that they are based on the so-called [Linux Genuine Advantage](http://www.linuxgenuineadvantage.org/faq/), a hoax licensing scheme for Linux which was meant as a parody of [Windows Genuine Advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Genuine_Advantage) (a Windows technology in Windows XP that was infamous for annoying legitimate users). Linux Genuine Advantage did not actually do anything, but it appears that someone has made this GLAT have a functional license server. Whoever they are, they might even be trying to collect money from people. If that's the case, it would be more of a scam than a hoax.

In either case, you should investigate how this program got on to your systems, as it may be an indication of security compromise.